# Create a void chart with jqplot LineChart

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I have a jqPlot chart that displays dynamically some values. I need the chart to be shown also when there's any value to show (displaying the grid, etc) but the chart disappears.

How to solve it?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', []);
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should use an if statement to see if there's data and if there isn't assign dummy data, like 0s.

Comment: yes, if there is no other choice... but I was looking for something more elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.
There is a parameter to solve that:

```
options.noDataIndicator = {    
                show: true, //Show the grid. It was false
                indicator: '',  //Show a message
                axes: { //axes info
                    xaxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 10,
                        tickInterval: 2,
                        show: false},
                    yaxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 12,
                        tickInterval: 3,
                        show: false}
                }
        };
```